# C - Function executing outside loop - Match 3 Game

Tags: c

I am trying to make a match 3 game in C.
Here is the full code of the game i've written so far - 
http://pastebin.com/sg5JZLz1

But for some reason in the code here (in the doIt() function) :

```
int x = 0;
while(x<SIZE) {
     // Remove vertical matches
    removeVerticals();
    // Remove horizontal matches
    removeHorizontals();
    // Move down
    moveDown(1); 
    printf("Ran : %d",x);
    x++;
}
```

the functions are executed only once and only the printf part is considered inside the loop.
Please excuse any of my bad coding practices as i am very new to C.

here is the output i get - 
[image]

Instead the output should be only the game board and Ran: 9 below that. It means the functions are not executing.

Comment: Screenshots of text, no!
Not lovely for programmers.
Copy-paste instead. (spamhaiku-style)

Comment: You should think on using gdb and step in the loop

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Ok i thought i was not required for the output. Just a min

Comment: Here's a paste of warnings from your paste of code. [**Start by fixing these**](http://pastebin.com/L9qsLtq6).

Comment: @WhozCraig im using Dev-C++ and im not getting any of those errors?!

Comment: @MaSK Turn up compiler warnings. Consult the compiler manual. The warning level is usually (=for most compilers) controlled with the -W switch.

Comment: @MaSK `and im not getting any of those errors?!` : in C you differentiate between errors and warnings. Warnings are when the compiler isn't dead certain that you're breaking the rules but has a good idea that you might be. I find it good taste to write C code that emits no warnings at all, because usually warnings are a sign that you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

No your function is working properly! it is executing `SIZE` times.

But the thing is you are using `system(cls);`. So it will clear the screen every time when it executes! so due to this you can't see the previous prints on the screen. so you will get only the last print on the screen.

Try this change-

```
moveDown(int printx) {
    int moved = 0,r;
    for (m=0; m<SIZE; m++) {
        moved = 0;
        for (i=0; i<SIZE-1; i++) {
            for (j=0;j<SIZE;j++) { 
                if (matrix[i+1][j] == ' ') {
                    matrix[i+1][j] = matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j] = ' ';
                    moved = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        i=0;
        for (j=0;j<SIZE;j++) { 
            r = rand_lim(5); // 0 to 5
            if (matrix[i][j] == ' ') {
                matrix[i][j] = arr[r];
            }
        }
        if(printx==1 && moved==1) {
             //system("cls");   // remove or comment out this line  <-- Note
             printScreen();
             // Remove vertical matches
             removeVerticals();
             // Remove horizontal matches
             removeHorizontals();
             waitForIt();
             moved = 0;
        }
    }
}
```